# SQL - numbers between two integer columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I'm trying to figure out a way to list all numbers between two columns (INT) and join them in a third column where all numbers are seperated.

Eg.

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 105 | 100;101;102;103;104;105 |
| 10 | 14 | 10;11;12;13;14 |

Does anyone have a solotion for this?

Have googled around but didnt find any exact match

Comment: Recursive cte, or join a tally table.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `generate_series` which is a function to generate a series of numbers between two values. with the help of `string_agg` function to concatenate these numbers into a single string, separated by semicolons:

```sql
SELECT
  column_a,
  column_b,
  string_agg(generated_number :: text, ';') AS column_c
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      column_a,
      column_b,
      generate_series(column_a, column_b) AS generated_number
    FROM
      your_table
  ) AS subquery
GROUP BY
  column_a,
  column_b;
```

[**dbfiddle DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/vmHhhrmw)

Answer (score 0):

Set-returning [`generate_series()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html) does just that: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/5S5pu2CZ)

```
create table test(start_ int, end_ int);
insert into test values (100,105),(10,14);

select start_, end_, string_agg(numbers_between::text,';') 
from test, generate_series(start_,end_)_(numbers_between)
group by start_, end_;
```

| start_ | end_ | string_agg |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 14 | 10;11;12;13;14 |
| 100 | 105 | 100;101;102;103;104;105 |

`String_agg()` does what you want but [`array_agg()` or `jsonb_agg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE) are preferable because they maintain the adequate type and allow you to subscript the resulting array.

In AWS Redshift flavour of PostgreSQL, `generate_series()` isn't supported, which is why you'd have to use a [recursive cte](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-RECURSIVE) [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77432454/sql-numbers-between-two-integer-columns/77432579#comment136509422_77432454) by [@jarlh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3706016/jarlh):

```sql
with recursive cte as(
  select start_,end_,start_ as number_between from test
  union all select start_,end_,number_between+1 from cte
  where number_between+1<=end_)
select start_,end_,string_agg(number_between::text,';')
from cte
group by start_,end_;
```

Which works in regular PostgreSQL as well.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this by using a recursive common table expression (CTE) to generate a series of numbers between two values. In this approach, you start with the initial values and then increment them until you reach the target value.

```
WITH RECURSIVE NumberList AS (
  SELECT column_a, column_b, column_a AS generated_number
  FROM your_table
  UNION ALL
  SELECT NumberList.column_a, NumberList.column_b, generated_number + 1
  FROM NumberList
  WHERE generated_number < NumberList.column_b
)
SELECT column_a, column_b, string_agg(generated_number::text, ';') AS column_c
FROM NumberList
GROUP BY column_a, column_b;
```

Simply replace your_table with the actual name of your table, and the query should work :).